# Installing Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text

Downloaded Ubuntu64 SublimeText from https://www.sublimetext.com/3

Double clicking opens Ubuntu Software, which seems to try to load endlessly

Opened terminal

```
cd Downloads
ls
sublime-text_build-3126_amd64.deb

exec sublime-text_build-3126_amd64.deb
bash: exec: sublime-text_build-3126_amd64.deb: not found
```

I'm sure this is very simple.

Answer (score 2):

Go into the folder where you downloaded it and run

`sudo apt-get install ./sublime-text_build-3126_amd64.deb`

Comment: Thank you. A bigger issue it seemed was the Ubuntu Software window constantly loading - I restarted and after that, simply clicking .deb installed other programs.

Answer (score 0):

Please do one of the following:

1. Use the Debian package installer `dpkg`

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-3126_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Use the `Software Center`: right click on the file and choose: `Open with software install`. When that opens `click install`, enter password when asked.

Comment: Be aware that if you install using `dpkg`, and the program you're using needs dependencies, the installation will fail because `dpkg` doesn't retrieve dependencies automatically.  `apt-get` will fetch, download, and install any required dependencies.

Comment: `exec` is a Bash command.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex didn't know that, ...

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use a ppa, as it's automatically installed and updated for you.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sublime-text-installer
```